# Mobile email client (http) can't display consecutive: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a buggy mobile email client (AquaMail) that ignores consecutive `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;`  It will only display a single `&nbsp;` the rest of the spaces are ignored.

If I try to use `style='white-space:pre;` as an alternative, it will allow me to use regular consecutive whitespaces, however, it exposes another bug... the email client will NOT detect and use regular carriage returns as whitespace while using this style! Regular carriage returns are completely ignored. If I try to use `<br>` while using that style, that fixes everything on that mobile email client, **however....** regular email clients that aren't broken will display double-carriage returns instead of a single carriage return.

Can anyone think of an alternative to `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` without implementing `style='white-space:pre;`?

Below, is the html code I tried to use.  It works perfectly in Outlook and all web browsers.  However, in my mobile client, the consecutive `&nbsp;&nbsp;` are ignored.

```html
06/16/21&nbsp;12:24:40am&nbsp;|&nbsp;broadband.actcorp.in&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/index3f35.html?page_id=8..&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;India&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Secunderabad,&nbsp;Telangana<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:20:28am&nbsp;|&nbsp;malware-hunter.census.shodan.io&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;INVALID:&nbsp;[]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;United&nbsp;States&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;San&nbsp;Diego,&nbsp;California<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:45:57am&nbsp;|&nbsp;zg-0609c-82.stretchoid.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/owa/auth/logon.aspx?url=..&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;United&nbsp;States&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;Palo&nbsp;Alto,&nbsp;California<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:58:22am&nbsp;|&nbsp;PT.&nbsp;Telekomunikasi&nbsp;Selular&nbsp;(Telkomsel)&nbsp;I..&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/login?dst=http%3A%2F%2Fc..&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;Indonesia&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jakarta,&nbsp;Jakarta<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:58:23am&nbsp;|&nbsp;PT.&nbsp;Telekomunikasi&nbsp;Selular&nbsp;(Telkomsel)&nbsp;I..&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/login?dst=http%3A%2F%2Fc..&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;Indonesia&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jakarta,&nbsp;Jakarta<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:58:25am&nbsp;|&nbsp;PT.&nbsp;Telekomunikasi&nbsp;Selular&nbsp;(Telkomsel)&nbsp;I..&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/favicon.ico&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;Indonesia&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Jakarta,&nbsp;Jakarta<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;02:08:16am&nbsp;|&nbsp;212-83-170-150.rev.poneytelecom.eu&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/?author=1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;France&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Saint-Ouen,&nbsp;Île-de-France<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;02:08:16am&nbsp;|&nbsp;212-83-170-150.rev.poneytelecom.eu&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;France&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Saint-Ouen,&nbsp;Île-de-France<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;02:08:17am&nbsp;|&nbsp;212-83-170-150.rev.poneytelecom.eu&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/xmlrpc.php&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;France&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Saint-Ouen,&nbsp;Île-de-France<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;02:08:17am&nbsp;|&nbsp;212-83-170-150.rev.poneytelecom.eu&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/xmlrpc.php&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;France&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Saint-Ouen,&nbsp;Île-de-France<br>
```

Below code works correctly in everything, including my mobile web browser:

```html
hi&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hi<br>
hi&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hi<br>
hi&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hi<br>
```

Comment: How about use `margin-left` or `margin-right` ?

Comment: Thanks.  But, I'm looking for a way to add the equivalent of the respective font's white-space character or &nbsp;.  `margin-left`  adds space based on pixels or percentage.  My HTML code is generated dynamically by a script, so it needs to be able to easily add exactly X number of space characters of the font being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use these things(`&nbsp;` `&ensp;` `&emsp;`)

```html
<p>hi&nbsp;hi</p>
<p>hi&ensp;hi</p>
<p>hi&emsp;hi</p>
```

I think if you use them properly(combination..?), you can get your goal

For example

```html
<span>You said this didn't work</span>
<p>hi&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;hi</p>

<span>How about try this?</span>
<p>hi&emsp;&nbsp;&emsp;&nbsp;&emsp;&nbsp;hi</p>

<span>Or this one</span>
<p>hi<span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span><span>&nbsp;</span>hi</p>
```

I replaced `&nbsp;&nbsp;` to `&ensp;`.

```html
06/16/21&nbsp;12:24:40am&nbsp;|&nbsp;broadband.actcorp.in&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/index3f35.html?page_id=8..&ensp;◄&nbsp;India&nbsp;►&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;Secunderabad,&nbsp;Telangana<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:20:28am&nbsp;|&nbsp;malware-hunter.census.shodan.io&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;INVALID:&nbsp;[]&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;United&nbsp;States&nbsp;►&ensp;San&nbsp;Diego,&nbsp;California<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:45:57am&nbsp;|&nbsp;zg-0609c-82.stretchoid.com&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/owa/auth/logon.aspx?url=..&ensp;◄&nbsp;United&nbsp;States&nbsp;►&ensp;Palo&nbsp;Alto,&nbsp;California<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:58:22am&nbsp;|&nbsp;PT.&nbsp;Telekomunikasi&nbsp;Selular&nbsp;(Telkomsel)&nbsp;I..&ensp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/login?dst=http%3A%2F%2Fc..&ensp;◄&nbsp;Indonesia&nbsp;►&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;Jakarta,&nbsp;Jakarta<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:58:23am&nbsp;|&nbsp;PT.&nbsp;Telekomunikasi&nbsp;Selular&nbsp;(Telkomsel)&nbsp;I..&ensp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/login?dst=http%3A%2F%2Fc..&ensp;◄&nbsp;Indonesia&nbsp;►&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;Jakarta,&nbsp;Jakarta<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;01:58:25am&nbsp;|&nbsp;PT.&nbsp;Telekomunikasi&nbsp;Selular&nbsp;(Telkomsel)&nbsp;I..&ensp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/favicon.ico&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;Indonesia&nbsp;►&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;Jakarta,&nbsp;Jakarta<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;02:08:16am&nbsp;|&nbsp;212-83-170-150.rev.poneytelecom.eu&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/?author=1&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;France&nbsp;►&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&nbsp;Saint-Ouen,&nbsp;Île-de-France<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;02:08:16am&nbsp;|&nbsp;212-83-170-150.rev.poneytelecom.eu&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;◄&nbsp;France&nbsp;►&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&nbsp;Saint-Ouen,&nbsp;Île-de-France<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;02:08:17am&nbsp;|&nbsp;212-83-170-150.rev.poneytelecom.eu&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/xmlrpc.php&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;◄&nbsp;France&nbsp;►&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&nbsp;Saint-Ouen,&nbsp;Île-de-France<br>
06/16/21&nbsp;02:08:17am&nbsp;|&nbsp;212-83-170-150.rev.poneytelecom.eu&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;|&nbsp;https://website.com/xmlrpc.php&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;◄&nbsp;France&nbsp;►&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&nbsp;Saint-Ouen,&nbsp;Île-de-France<br>
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, how do I, for example, specify 15 space characters using the example you have me?

Comment: Your example works great in my mobile web browser and all other web browsers.  However, when I try to use my own HTML code, consecutive `&nbsp;&nbsp;` are ignored.  Can you please look at the example I just posted?  I just edited my original question to include the actual code that doesn't work correctly.  I am hoping you can figure out a clever way to make it work.

Comment: Your example `<span>&nbsp;</span>` worked perfectly!  Thank you!